# Why doesn't this Vim macro work?

Tags: neovim, macro

I recorded this macro to register `a` in Neovim by first pressing `qa`:

**Macro**

```
--- Registers ---
"a   f1F1i-^[la0^[j
```

Then I pressed `q` and my cursor was left in normal mode at the position marked by `|` (so that `m` is highlighted) in the below JavaScript snippet (on line `4`).

**JavaScript snippet**

```
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    mw_panel.style.left="-10em";
    mw_head.style.left="-10em";
    content.style.left="1e|m";
    left_navigation.style.left="1em";
    footer.style.left="1em";
  }, 350);
```

Then I tried to apply the macro with `@a` but nothing happened. I tried the same in Vim and nothing happened. Though the macro will move the cursor to the `1` if I move it away before using it. Am I not understanding something about how Vim macros work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros abort when they fail at some point. In your example, `f1` fails since there is no `1` after the cursor. To solve it, you can set `"a` to, say, `0f1i-^[la0^[j`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use sdp's suggestion `0f1i-^[la0^[j` in a case like this, but my original macro could "directly" be made to work by absorbing the errors by the method described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/337825):

```
:try|exe "norm! f1"|endtry|try|exe "norm! F1"|endtry^Mi-^[la0^[j
```